# Image control with source set to unavailable UNC path causes very slow performance

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access form with an Image control, the control source for which is a string field called PhotoPath. If the PhotoPath points to a non-existent UNC path, the form takes over a minute to open.

The form opens quickly if:
1. The PhotoPath points to a file which is available, OR
2. The PhotoPath is null
3. The PhotoPath points to a file on a non-existent drive, such as D:\MyPhoto.jpg (where there is no D: drive)

However, if the PhotoPath contains a UNC Path, such as \Server\Images\MyPhoto.jpg then the form takes over a minute to open.

Unfortunately, I can't use mapped drives to bypass the problem, because my client doesn't have the same mappings for all staff who need to use the database.

I have code in the Form_Current event to try to test if the file exists, and remove it as the source of the control if not:

```
If IsNull(Me.strPhotoPath) Then
    Debug.Print "No photo"

Else
    Debug.Print "Have photo"

    If CheckFileExists(Me.strPhotoPath) Then
        Me.imgStudentPhoto.Picture = Me.strPhotoPath
        Me.imgStudentPhoto.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.imgStudentPhoto.Picture = ""
        Me.imgStudentPhoto.Visible = False
    End If
End If
```

However, this isn't helping, as the CheckFileExists code is equally slow in testing for whether the file exists.

Here's the CheckFileExists code:

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
CheckFileExists = fso.FileExists(FilePath)
```

There are no errors displayed, and everything generates the expected results, but the performance is unacceptably slow when trying to access a non-existent UNC path.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with regard to the response time of `FileExists`. On my network, `FileExists` consistently returns the correct value in less than half a second whether the file/path exists or not. In your case, when the file does not exist is the *folder path* valid but the file simply isn't there? If so, is it a folder with a very large number of files in it?

Comment: Looking for a non-existent server takes a lot of time. If you'd start by checking the server against a list of allowed servers this probably wouldn't occur.

Comment: Gord: Thanks for the suggestion. The server, folder and indeed file path are all valid, in the sense that they're correct for the person who added them. However, for another user, on a different network, there is no such folder as \\Server1 (or whatever) and it's in that situation that the performance drops off.

Comment: Erik: Thanks for the idea. I'll have a ponder about how / whether I could implement that. The issue is that different people in different departments appear to have different servers available, so the list of "valid" servers isn't a fixed thing.

Comment: Since VBA does not support multi threading, an idea could be to execute an external program asynchronously on startup of your Access Application (which you would have to write maybe). You would 'feed' it with the possible UNC paths and it collects in the background their accessability, returning that information maybe in a text file, which is polled by your Access app from time to time. So your Access application won't hang.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Dir` function instead of FSO.

Replace

```
If IsNull(Me.strPhotoPath) Then
```

With

```
If Len(Dir(Me.strPhotoPath)) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for that suggestion. I tried, but got no improvement in performance. Additionally, where the PhotoPath is a UNC path, I now get VBA Error 52 (Bad file name or number). So, sadly, no luck there.

Comment: It seems that the issue is inherent in the Windows file system. One thing you could try, if the invalid path is due to an invalid host name, is try a ping to see if a computer with such a name exists. You may also want to look into whether there is a registry entry that defines the timeout value for trying to access network shares.

Answer (score 0):

You could, initially, check for the path to be possibly valid:

```
\Server\Images\MyPhoto.jpg
```

is not, while:

```
\\Server\Images\MyPhoto.jpg
```

could be valid.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the idea. All the paths are technically valid (they start with a double-back-slash) but the server doesn't exist on the network.

Comment: Incidentally, I now notice that the example UNC path I gave in my original post was invalid - that was a typo on my part rather than an example of their data!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is you can do all kinds of dir() commands etc. The bottom line is if a image control attempts to resolve to a un-available network path, you going to get a huge delay.

However, what you can do is on application startup set a global var if the folder is available, or not.

Then, for those controls that have a path name such as:

```
\\server01\Pictures\house.png
```

You replace the above source with a function like this:

=GetPicture('\server01\house.png')

So the source of the picture can be a VBA function.

Now, your function can look like this:

```
Public Function GetPicture(s as String) as string
  if gblFolder = True then
     GetPicture = s
  Else
     GetPicture = ""
  End If
End Function
```

The result now is that the function returns nothing when you set the gblFolder flag on application startup. This will then in turn prevent the huge slow network resolution process that Access attempts. If the application is not a compiled accDE (it should be), then I would suggest placing the true/false value into a temp!var, since with a accDB, any un-handled error at any time will blow out and re-set all global VBA variables. However, if you use a accDE,then any and all variables are NEVER re-set for the given access session, and you can thus freely persist VBA varibles - they are never re-set for any reason or any un-handled error if you use a accDE as opposed to accDB.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in coming back to you. Yes, that makes sense as an approach, and I'll try it (am working with a different client right now so can't test until I return there next week). I'm interested - why such the long delay for UNC paths but not, apparently, for mapped drives? Is it that Windows resolves whether the path exists for mapped drives as part of the boot up mapping process before Access ever attempts to get to that drive, and so is able to deliver a much quicker response?

Comment: Well, often do see just as long as delay  with a mapped drive also. So, anything that point to a non existing (non available) path, be it UNC or a mapped drive? Well, if either one is  not available, the result is a rather long delay.